# Laravel Version, PHP Version and Composer Version Compatibility Issue

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have installed PHP version 7.3.33, composer 1.1 and running multiple laravel 7.x projects.

Now I am trying to install two different Laravel Projects. One with Laravel 9 and the other with 7.x.

If I update the PHP and Composer Version, it will create issues in existing laravel 7.x projects.

Is there any way to Upgrade/ make compatible the old laravel projects to composer 2 and new PHP version.

```
    Problem 1
    - This package requires php ^8.0.2 but your PHP version (7.4.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v9.1.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v9.1.0].
    - laravel/framework v9.1.0 requires php ^8.0.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for league/flysystem 3.0.8 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[3.0.8].
    - league/flysystem 3.0.8 requires php ^8.0.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 4
    - Installation request for psr/log 3.0.0 -> satisfiable by psr/log[3.0.0].
    - psr/log 3.0.0 requires php >=8.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 5
    - Installation request for psr/simple-cache 3.0.0 -> satisfiable by psr/simple-cache[3.0.0].
    - psr/simple-cache 3.0.0 requires php >=8.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 6
    - Installation request for symfony/console v6.0.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v6.0.3].
    - symfony/console v6.0.3 requires php >=8.0.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 7
    - Installation request for symfony/css-selector v6.0.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/css-selector[v6.0.3].
    - symfony/css-selector v6.0.3 requires php >=8.0.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 8
    - Installation request for symfony/deprecation-contracts v3.0.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/deprecation-contracts[v3.0.0].
    - symfony/deprecation-contracts v3.0.0 requires php >=8.0.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 9
    - Installation request for symfony/error-handler v6.0.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/error-handler[v6.0.3].
    - symfony/error-handler v6.0.3 requires php >=8.0.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 10
    - Installation request for symfony/event-dispatcher v6.0.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher[v6.0.3].
    - symfony/event-dispatcher v6.0.3 requires php >=8.0.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 11
    - Installation request for symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts v3.0.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts[v3.0.0].
    - symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts v3.0.0 requires php >=8.0.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 12
    - Installation request for symfony/finder v6.0.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/finder[v6.0.3].
    - symfony/finder v6.0.3 requires php >=8.0.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 13
    - Installation request for symfony/http-foundation v6.0.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[v6.0.3].
    - symfony/http-foundation v6.0.3 requires php >=8.0.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 14
    - Installation request for symfony/http-kernel v6.0.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[v6.0.4].
    - symfony/http-kernel v6.0.4 requires php >=8.0.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 15
    - Installation request for symfony/mailer v6.0.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/mailer[v6.0.3].
    - symfony/mailer v6.0.3 requires php >=8.0.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 16
    - Installation request for symfony/mime v6.0.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/mime[v6.0.3].
    - symfony/mime v6.0.3 requires php >=8.0.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 17
    - Installation request for symfony/process v6.0.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v6.0.3].
    - symfony/process v6.0.3 requires php >=8.0.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 18
    - Installation request for symfony/routing v6.0.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/routing[v6.0.3].
    - symfony/routing v6.0.3 requires php >=8.0.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 19
    - Installation request for symfony/service-contracts v3.0.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/service-contracts[v3.0.0].
    - symfony/service-contracts v3.0.0 requires php >=8.0.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 20
    - Installation request for symfony/string v6.0.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/string[v6.0.3].
    - symfony/string v6.0.3 requires php >=8.0.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 21
    - Installation request for symfony/translation v6.0.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/translation[v6.0.3].
    - symfony/translation v6.0.3 requires php >=8.0.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 22
    - Installation request for symfony/translation-contracts v3.0.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/translation-contracts[v3.0.0].
    - symfony/translation-contracts v3.0.0 requires php >=8.0.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 23
    - Installation request for symfony/var-dumper v6.0.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v6.0.3].
    - symfony/var-dumper v6.0.3 requires php >=8.0.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 24
    - Installation request for nunomaduro/collision v6.1.0 -> satisfiable by nunomaduro/collision[v6.1.0].
    - nunomaduro/collision v6.1.0 requires php ^8.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 25
    - Installation request for spatie/flare-client-php 1.0.2 -> satisfiable by spatie/flare-client-php[1.0.2].
    - spatie/flare-client-php 1.0.2 requires php ^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 26
    - Installation request for spatie/ignition 1.0.5 -> satisfiable by spatie/ignition[1.0.5].
    - spatie/ignition 1.0.5 requires php ^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 27
    - Installation request for spatie/laravel-ignition 1.0.6 -> satisfiable by spatie/laravel-ignition[1.0.6].
    - spatie/laravel-ignition 1.0.6 requires php ^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 28
    - laravel/framework v9.1.0 requires php ^8.0.2 -> your PHP version (7.4.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/sail v1.13.4 requires illuminate/console ^8.0|^9.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v9.1.0].
    - Installation request for laravel/sail v1.13.4 -> satisfiable by laravel/sail[v1.13.4].
```

Comment: this seems like an environment issue. One laravel version runs on PHP 7, while the other requires PHP 8+. So if you want to keep both of those running you have to find a way to run both php versions (or update the oldest project to the newest laravel version)

Comment: I am working on Local. I already tried with Laragon. But composer error still remains. If I update the composer, all existing projects will stop working. How can fix composer issue? Currently I am using XAMPP. Can I use both XAMPP and Laragon at the same time.?

Comment: "If I update the composer, all existing projects will stop working". What does this mean? Are you updating the version of Composer or are you running `composer update` inside your project to update the `composer.json` versions? For the last case, you should never be able to screw up other projects since you are working in a project context.

Comment: you can try to install latest XAMPP on different drive and can use that for the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on windows and how I combat this is by downloading the versions of PHP I desire and putting them inside folders that are within the same directory.
Inside `parent folder` I have `php72` `php74` `php8`.

Then I edit my path location in my terminal and point to that same folder however I reference the folder `php`.

Assuming in my directory I have `php72` `php74` `php8` and I wish to use `php8` I would rename that folder to just `php`

Now my directory looks like this `php72` `php74` `php`

If I need to change to php72 I would rename the directories as below
`php` `php74` `php8`

I also implement a similar solution for composer

It's a bit of weird hacky way, however its easy to implement and works for me, hopefully it can for you too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new environment for the laravel 9 since it's not compatible with php 7. You can do it with docker `Laravel sail`  or Virtual Machine `Laravel homestead`.

If you'r on a `production environment`, i recommend you to use another server instance or deploy in a container.
In other way, you also can use PHP-FPM with Apache / Nginx.

If you're on `Local environment` and don't have any knowledge of admin system / devops, you can use `Laragon` or `Wamp` and install different version of PHP

Comment: I am working on Local. I already tried with Laragon. But composer error still remains. If I update the composer, all existing projects will stop working. How can fix composer issue? Currently I am using XAMPP. Can I use both XAMPP and Laragon at the same time.?

Answer (score 0):

It's because in your project in composer.json file you have:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.4",
    .....
},
```

Try to update this requirement to:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.4|^8.0",
    .....
},
```

Or another option if you wouldn't to install any new version PHP you can do this. It will ignore reqs.

```
 composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. I solved it with this:

```
composer require laravel/sail:*
```

Answer (score 0):

This needs to change your PHP version use the next:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

[image]

**Type selection number: 5**
to chose the version php8.0